# How to manually edit the link to share in google drive or google photos

Tags: google-drive-android-api, google-photos

When the photos are uploaded in Google drive or Google photos and shared to others, the link will be ​https://docs.google.com/xyz. However is there anyway to convert this into meaningful link like [Link to Presentation 2017](http://Link%20to%20Presentation%202017) ??

Answer (score 2):

This option is currently not available for Google Drive or Google Photos.

Some good references:

- [How to change / modify shareable Google Drive link?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/sA8WB2joD8w) (which mentions the same, option is currently not available)
- [Is it possible to have clean URLs for Google Drive items?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29519/154267) (accepted answer discusses why the URLs should stay as they are)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Is there any way to map useful name to link. Like when we click on Link to Presentation 2017 it will internally call the link given by google drive.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you could just diaplay it as a hyperlink. But for APIs you could use, I haven't found any custom URL creators in a while (bit.ly used to, but they removed it). Most APIs you'll see would just be URL shortening.

Answer (score 0):

Trick for Google Drive (Perhaps it works with photos too)

**Make a copy of the folder or file.**

Now you have a different link.